# Ad Medaition for Android/iPhone App - Server Side

Tags: android, iphone, admob, mopub

I am about to complete my first game app and was planning to integrate an ad network but then I heard about Ad Mediation. My question is: If I am using an ad mediator like MoPub, will it be possible to do server side addition/removal of third party ad network **after** the release of the app?  ie. suppose if I am using an ad mediator and for the time being, the only ad network I am included is AdMob. If AdMob bans me for whatever reasons, will I be able to replace AdMob with another network without having to release an update of my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different ad network mediators have different features, but most will have server to server integrated ad networks (no SDK), javascript tag integrated networks (no sdk), and sdk integrated networks (requires the integration of an sdk).

In an ad network mediation platform, you will be able to add/remove/turn on/pause networks you have integrated.

Server to server networks can be integrated in the UI and can be done even after you release your app as the network mediation sdk has all it needs to serve these ads.

For networks that do require sdk integration, you will only be able to serve ads from these networks if you have integrated the network sdk with the mediation platform's sdk.

For javascript tag based networks, this will depend on if you have to integrate a custom adapter into the mediation platform's sdk or if you can implement the javascript tags directly in the mediation platform's UI.

Please note that most networks on most mediation platforms are integrated through sdk. You should integrate all the networks you plan on using.